# How to curve particles?

Tags: particles

I wonder how I can achieve emitted particle objects being bended like below?

I tried emitting objects that are straight with the curve modifier and following a curve guide. Though, they don't curve the emitted object.

My only solution so far is to create a lot of meshes manually representing those "strains" and add curve modifiers on each and add a follow path constraint to follow the curve. Though this method doesn't scale well if you want a huge number of strains.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use hair particles for the wires/"strains"?

Comment: They get emitted, they are not "rooted".

Comment: Can you describe more what you want to achieve? If you just want to have "wires" as shown on the image then you can get away with hair particles. If you want to have particles fly around in space then you need to use emitter particles. But emitter particles can't have a "trail" (I might be wrong). Basically, you can use a Curve Guide force field to bend particles. And you can use 2 systems for something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiS6R.jpg.

Comment: Thanks @Blunder for taking time to answer. I basically want the strain to fly around and bend according to a curve I set. I don't want just hair to be curved and prolonged with "roots" on a particular face.

Think of an air flow simulation.

I'm quite a newbie in Blender. Just a few months experience.